# Listening for Auth events in Dingo API laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I used [Dingo API package](https://github.com/dingo/api) to create an api like **Telegram** api.

In the first step User sends some parameters , then I verify those and if all things was true user informations included a Token returned. like this :

```
public function signIn (Request $request)
{
    $phone_number    = $request->get('phone_number');
    $phone_code_hash = $request->get('phone_code_hash');
    $phone_code      = $request->get('phone_code');

    if ($this->verifyCode($phone_code_hash, $phone_code, $phone_number)) {
        $user = User::where('phone_number', $phone_number)->firstOrFail();
        $user->injectToken();
        return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer);
    } else {    
        return [
            'success'     => false,
            'type'        => 'PHONE_NUMBER_IS_NOT_REGISTERED',
            'code'        => 703,
            'message'     => 'Phone Code Is Correct But Phone Number Is Not Registered.'
        ];
    }
}
```

As you can see `signIn` method has user authentication duty.

Now I do not know how can I listen to authentication events like `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated` ,`Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` and etc described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#events).

In fact I want to run an event whenever user login was successfull.

I'm using larvel 5.3.

Any solution ؟

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These events are not supported out of the box by Dingo.

You may however, create a custom middleware to fire an `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated` event on success like so:

app/Http/Middleware/Auth.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Auth as BaseAuth;
use Closure;

class Auth extends BaseAuth {

     /**
     * Perform authentication before a request is executed.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = $this->router->getCurrentRoute();
        if (! $this->auth->check(false)) {
            $this->auth->authenticate($route->getAuthenticationProviders());
            event(new \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Authenticated($this->auth->getUser());
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Finally, just register and add this middleware to your routes